# how to calculate the sum of a object with a watch function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to calculate the sum of a object properties on user input. i have a function setup with a watch but i am not getting the result. i have a fiddle with what i have. 
[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qy5t4kv3/)

```
 $scope.model = {}
    function total() {
        var totalNumber = 0;
        totalNumber = totalNumber + $scope.model.minPrice + $scope.model.maxPrice + $scope.model.occup

        return totalNumber;
    };
    $scope.$watch('model', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        $scope.model.total = total();
        console.log($scope.model.total)
    }, true);
```

and screenshot of console

[image: console]

Comment: Seems you're adding up strings, and the occasional `undefined`. You probably want to do some type checking and conversion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` operator is overloaded to concatenate strings.

One option is to cast your strings to integers using `parseInt()` before adding them. You can use an logical OR operator to take care of `NaN` as well. This is just one way.

```
totalNumber = (parseInt($scope.model.minPrice) || 0)
  + (parseInt($scope.model.maxPrice) || 0)
  + (parseInt($scope.model.occup) || 0);
  console.log($scope.model);
```

[Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/qy5t4kv3/3/)

Comment: im not seeing the total amount in the console?

Comment: @texas697 apologies, missed a small logic bomb. Updated/fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a simple as this, though you'll want to filter for empty and invalid values.

```
$scope.$watch('model', function() {
  $scope.model.total = parseInt($scope.model.minPrice) 
    + parseInt($scope.model.maxPrice) 
    + parseInt($scope.model.occup);
}, true);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/hfua0a5b/)**